# Экспорт базы данных по дате laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, не могу экспортировать базу по дате. 
Мой контроллер

```
public function export2(Request $request)
{
    $dateStart = $request->dateStart;
    $dateFinish = $request->dateFinish;
    $table = orders::where($dateStart, $dateFinish)->all();
    $filename = "test2.csv";
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    // fprintf($handle, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
    fputs($handle, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)); // BOM
    @fputcsv($handle, array('sep=,'));
    fputcsv($handle, array('description','phone'));

    foreach($table as $row) {
        fputcsv($handle, array(iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $row['name']), iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $row['description']), iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $row['staticprice'])));
    }

    fclose($handle);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    );

    return Response::download($filename, 'test.csv', $headers);
}
```

Мой select

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-12 00:00:00'
```

и мой шаблон

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('export2') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <input type="date" name="imagedelete">
    <input type="date" name="imagedelete">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect">Экспортировать</button>
</form>
```

Ошибка

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()
```

Помогите плиз

Comment: В чем заключается ваша проблема?

Comment: поправил, забыл написать ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$table = orders::where($dateStart, $dateFinish)->all();`

Здесь есть 2 ошибки:

1. Либо вы применяете Model::all() и получаете все записи, либо вы добавляете условия и используете метод get().

`Model::where('name', 'John')->get();`

2. У вас неправильно задано условие поиска по дате
   Должно быть как-то так

`$table = Order::where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d', $dateStart))->where('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', $dateFinish))->get();`

Comment: A non well formed numeric value encountered             $table = orders::where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'))->where('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d', '2019-01-12 00:00:00'))->get();
        dd($table);

Comment: ->whereBetween('created_at', [$dateStart, $dateFinish])